# Run a background every day (even if the PC is shut down at midnight)

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, background-process

In my UWP app I was able to run a background task every day at midnight but I also need that if the computer is not on at midnight the task will run the next time the computer is turned on, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can not you run the task in the boot application?

Comment: Seems like a perfect job for [Windows Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx). In fact, I'd move the midnight task to it as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the UWP background task model you can register your task with a SystemTrigger of type SessionConnected. This will run when the user logs on. Then you can check if you have missed the midnight task and handle this according to your needs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.SystemTriggerType